# javax.naming.ConfigurationException NamingManager.getURLContext cannot find the factory for this scheme: java after migrating to WAS 8.5 and java 1.7

Tags: java, spring, websphere-8

After migrating the application from Java 5 to 7 and WAS 6.1 to WAS 8.5.5.1, while deploying the application, I am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: NamingManager.getURLContext cannot find the factory for this scheme: java
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.checkForUrlContext(Helpers.java:1631)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:160)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:86)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:122)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:147)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:90)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1024)
```

This is coming from a spring context file which is inside a Jar which I can't modify. Here is the context file contents:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean lazy-init="true" id="test-jndiLocalContext" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I have followed the suggestion given in [javax.naming.ConfigurationException after migrating to WAS 8.5 and java 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041353/javax-naming-configurationexception-after-migrating-to-was-8-5-and-java-1-7) 
and in https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2014/06/15/how-to-fix-ibm-websphere-jndi-exception-cannot-find-the-factory-for-this-scheme-java/

Changed the web-app version from 2.4 to 2.5 and converted ibm-web-bnd.xmi to ibm-web-bnd.xml file, but no luck. It still gives me the same problem. Looks like the issue is in the Jar file that contains the spring context xml.

Can anyone suggest possible advise or solution.

Many thanks

Comment: Try 3.0 `web.xml`, and also check if `application.xml` version is 6, maybe you have some old version there.

Comment: @Gas Thanks for your response. I tried with 3.0 and changed application.xml file from 1.4 to 6 as below:
'<application id="Application_ID" version="6" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd">' but no luck. It still gives me the same error.