# javax.naming.ConfigurationException: NamingManager.getURLContext cannot find the factory for this scheme: java

Tags: ejb, websphere

I have an EAR that runs under WebSphere 6.1.  I'm trying to port it over to WebSphere 8.5.5.  The WAR within the EAR cannot access session beans.  Here is the stack trace:

```
2019-04-16 11:01:04,619 ERROR - javax.naming.ConfigurationException: NamingManager.getURLContext cannot find the factory for this scheme: java
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.checkForUrlContext(Helpers.java:1631)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:160)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.dc.common.ContextLookup.getEnterpriseBean(ContextLookup.java:61)
    at com.dc.storefront.b2b.actions.MaintenanceAction.getConfigSess(MaintenanceAction.java:959)
    at com.dc.storefront.b2b.actions.LoginAction.executeAdditionalActions(LoginAction.java:203)
    at com.dc.storefront.b2b.actions.MaintenanceAction.execute(MaintenanceAction.java:515)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1056)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:388)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:231)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:564)
    at com.ibm._jsp._home._jspService(_home.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:620)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

I tried the solution posted here [javax.naming.ConfigurationException after migrating to WAS 8.5 and java 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041353/javax-naming-configurationexception-after-migrating-to-was-8-5-and-java-1-7), but the code seems to have an issue with how resources are associated between my web.xml and ibm-web-bnd.xmi:

```
<!-- ibm-web-bnd.xmi to 
        xml transformation exception: Found resRefBindings with id ResourceRef_1250177725156 
        that has no matching reference in web.xml -->
```

I can find that resource reference in the web.xml, so I'm not sure what the issue is with that solution.

The WAR file project facet for **Dynamic Web Module** is 2.4

The EJB project facet for **EJB Module** is 2.0.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve the issue with my WAR not being able to access the resource beans?

EJB Lookup code in the Struts Action class:

```
protected ConfigSessLocal getConfigSess() throws StorefrontException
    {
        ConfigSessLocalHome home = null;
        ConfigSessLocal sess = null;

        try
        {
            home = (ConfigSessLocalHome) getContextLookup().getEnterpriseBean("ConfigSessJNDI");  // Error is here
            sess = home.create();
        }
        catch (NamingException e)
        {
            throw new StorefrontException("Action: getConfigSess:" + " error looking up session bean", e);
        }
        catch (CreateException e)
        {
            throw new StorefrontException("Action: getConfigSess:" + " error looking up session bean", e);
        }
        return sess;
    }

public Object getEnterpriseBean(String envVarName) throws NamingException
    {
        Object bean = null;
        String jndiName = null;

        if (_context == null)
        {
            _context = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
        }
        jndiName = getEnvVarValue(envVarName);
        bean = _context.lookup(jndiName);

        return bean;
    }
```

Comment: Get the migration tools from wasdev.net (either toolkit for binaries, or plugin for Eclipse) and scan your application. It will highlight the issues that you have to fix for migration. Otherwise include contents of `web.xml` and `ibm-web-bnd.xmi` files in the question.

Comment: My RAD 9.0 installation did not have the option to do a "WebSphere Application Server Version Migration" analysis.  I have BIRT and WDT installed in it.  RAD doesn't come with Eclipse Marketplace, and I could not find a way to install that toll via Installation Manager.

Comment: I downloaded Eclipse Photon and installed the IBM WebSphere Application Server Migration Toolkit and WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools plugins into that environment.  I ran the Software Analyzer for everything, but did not see the tool come up with anything for the EJB XML files beyond deprecated use of reload attributes in ibm-web-ext.xmi.  I'll attach the two files you mentioned to this question.

Comment: @Gas The two files were too long to be added directly to the question, so I included them as answers.  Not sure how else to include them here.  Hopefully forum moderators don't come after me!

Comment: I saw the contents of the files. Usually you have to host them somewhere and attach the links. Please post what you are trying to lookup here `com.dc.common.ContextLookup.getEnterpriseBean(ContextLookup.java:61)`

Comment: I see you have webapp version 2.4, so you should be using ibm-web-bnd.xmi NOT ibm-web-bnd.xml (i not l at the end).

Comment: @Gas Ok, I thought maybe I needed to use the XML file to resolve the issue.  I updated my question to include the EJB lookup code.  Appreciate your help!